# Start a process with different DLL path in C#

Tags: c#, dll, environment-variables

I am starting a Process with Process.Start("MyProcess.exe") function.

"MyProcess.exe" uses a DLL. Exe and DLL are in same folder.

I have modified this DLL and located it into a different path with same name.

For some cases, I want to start MyProcess.exe with modified DLL and I do not want to delete original DLL.

My Exe should work with seconds DLL that located different folder and should not work with DLL that located same folder.

I have tried following codes but does not work for me

```
processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = "PATH_B;" + processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"];

processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName("PATH_B");
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

myProcess = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: Is the DLL a .NET dll or a native one?

Comment: You can redirect compile-time bindings to other assemblies through the app configuration file. Take a look at [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the built in [rules within the operating system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the system always searches directories in the following order:

- The directory from which the application loaded.
- The system directory.
- The 16-bit system directory.
- The Windows directory.
- The current directory.
- The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL have the different version you casu use

[Specifying an Assembly's Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.110).aspx)

in the config file of MyProcess.exe if is .Net